# nginx proxy server get random ERR_CONNECTION_RESET when calling from outside

Tags: javascript, nginx, https, proxy

I have a vps where I host my API. For some reason I sometimes get random ERR_CONNECTION_RESET errors when I make HTTPS call my server on localhost or another server. I think my config looks ok but the weirdest thing is that it sometimes work

I use nginx as a front service for my API which redirects to the 9999 port

Here is my nginx config

```
server {
    server_name mysite.fr www.mysite.fr;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9999;
    }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.fr/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mysite.fr/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.mysite.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = mysite.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name mysite.fr www.mysite.fr;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Comment: Your config looks fine for me too. Can you have a look at the nginx logs? Maybe you can see something there. I could think about that the requests with `ERR_CONNECTION_RESET` wont even show up there. If you can confirm that, you can be sure its nothing with nginx, so it might just be the server that is badly available.